# Toggle buttons issue

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

If I click on search icon it will open back button and search bar. Again I click on the back button it will open search icon

I tried with inner html.

If I click on search icon I used innerhtml to display back button and search bar.
But if I click on back button how to render search icon?

```js
container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `
  <header>
    <div id="chat-icon">
      <div class="search"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></div>
      <div id="chat"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="group-list"></div>`);

container.querySelector('header #chat-icon #chat').addEventListener('click', async() => {
  this.chat.container.querySelector('.groups').remove();
  this.chat.container.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', this.createGroup.container);
  await this.createGroup.load();
});

container.querySelector('header .search').addEventListener('click', async() => {
  this.chat.container.querySelector('header .search').innerHTML = `
    <div class="heading">
      <div id="back-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
      <div id="search-bar"></div>   
    </div>`
})
```

Comment: Consider [`.hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [`.show()`](https://api.jquery.com/show/) instead of `.remove()` and adding HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `.remove()` and `.load()`, you can use `.hide` to hide the searchbar and `.show()` to show it.

Comment: This is for showing search bar and back button inside searchicon      container.querySelector('header .search').addEventListener('click', async() => {
  this.chat.container.querySelector('header .search').innerHTML = `
    <div class="heading">
      <div id="back-button"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></div>
      <div id="search-bar"></div>   
    </div>`
})this.chat.container.querySelector('#back-button').addEventListener('click', async () {
     this.chat.container.querySelector('.heading').innerhtml = `<i class=fas fa-search</i>`});
     
     
    });

Comment: Can i ask you why you want to change the html of an element only using .innerthml?? Let javascript change the html for you with functions like .hide() or .show(), it will work better and is more easy to read.

Comment: how to change by using hide and show  write the code for above

Comment: i made an example: instead of `this.chat.container.querySelector('.heading').innerhtml = <i class=fas fa-search</i>` you can write `this.chat.container.querySelector('.heading').show()`
Remember to upvote comments or answers if you find it useful

Comment: i tried like this but its showing error Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.chat.container.querySelector(...).hide is not a function

Comment: Maybe if you use `getelementbyid("chat-icon").hide()` it works better

Comment: no it is not working showing error Uncaught TypeError: this.chat.container.getelementbyid is not a function

Comment: what i need to do means ---there is a heading in that heading search icon and edit is there If i click on the search icon it will show the back button and searchbar and if i click on the back button it will show the search previous icon